# Все ли знаки препинания поставлены?

Tags: пунктуация

"Вытряхивал все из сумки в поисках сигарет, телефона и плеера".

Answer (score 1):

Знаки поставлены все. Вероятно, вас смущает слово *все* и вы думали про двоеточие? Но это слово не является обобщающим в данном предложении. Нечего обобщать. Ср.: Вытаскивал из сумки все: кошелек, записную книжку, ключи - в поисках телефона.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно. запятая здесь разделяет однородные члены.